# failure to shutdown from ssh when on wifi

Tags: ssh, shutdown

I seem to be able to shutdown my raspberry remotely over ssh using

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

when I'm connected through ethernet - yet, when it's connected over wifi whenever I run this (or some similar command) nothing happens.. the ssh simply freezes there forever and if I interrupt with Ctrl-C I can still login back to the raspberry.

am I missing something?

(running the latest raspbian-lite on a raspberry pi 3 and ssh-ing from a macbook pro)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I've observed this just plain not work before, although calling `shutdown` in an ssh session may often cause it to hang on your side.  I'll hazard a guess and say the reason you have this problem with wifi but not ethernet is because of the bit of latency involved.  TBH that's a dubious, unsatisfying guess, but I don't think we need a complete understanding.

The way I deal with shutdown via ssh is to send the command into the background and exit.  My personal preference is actually `halt -p` but I am not sure if that matters:

```
sudo halt -p & exit
```

To explain: `&` backgrounds a process, meaning the call returns immediately, before the command itself completes.  Shutting down the system usually takes at least a few seconds before the final move, which is to tell the hardware to poweroff (I'm not sure how meaningful that is on the pi -- so the `-p` may just be an irrelevant habit).

The `exit` then refers to the ssh login, so that will then be immediately disconnected properly.  The way the timing works out is that `halt` on the other end won't have stopped `sshd` yet, so no snags.

Beware:

- Using this method (`foo & exit`) with most processes will probably end up with the process failing or dying mysteriously.  It works with `halt` (or `shutdown`) because these are actually commands to the init system.  Not a complete explanation, but enough said here.
- `foo & bar` is very different than `foo && bar`.  The latter means wait for `foo` to finish executing and then only start `bar` if `foo` succeeded.  That's not what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I do this all the time with my Pi which run headless, although I use `sudo poweroff`. This works reliably and the host indicates connection lost.

It is probably a timing issue.

`shutdown` and `poweroff` all use the same code, but `poweroff` causes the activity LED to flash 10 times at 1 second intervals.

I have found some settings interfere with shutdown - `dtoverlay=gpio-poweroff` certainly does.